# Returning int array from c++ .dll to c#

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, dll

I need to send a array of numbers from c# to a .dll writen in ++ sort them and get them back for displaying.

Currently I am sending the data but I can't seem to get them back in the correct format. The program crashes or returns something random.

This is the definiton :

```
[DllImport("kmp.dll",CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern IntPtr sort([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] int[] vhod);
```

This is how I call it.

```
sorted = sort(numbers);
```

The c++ function

```
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) const int* sort(const int arr[])
{
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: If you're sorting the array, why do you need to return the pointer?  The array is sorted in place, isn't it?

Comment: well i put a pointer in there because i cant find another way to return the array. And i know its uselles but the best i got. I cant put int[] in the function or can i ?

Comment: What I'm saying is that you need not return anything.  You're taking the data and you're sorting it in place.  On return, that same array you passed in should have sorted data.  If not, then you need to post this sort() function.  In addition, I would highly suggest you give the DLL function the number of elements in the array.  There is no way for the sort() function to really know how many elements it's sorting.

Comment: i didnt work in C so long i forgot i can reference a pointer. Thank you. Can u please write down what do i need to redefine. Tried *number and it kinda doesnt work. I already didt the size thing. Thank you

Comment: Actually i fell like an dummy now. It works thank you. Can u please write this downa as an awnser ? I want to give you points for that.

Comment: ok.  Answer given below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the prototype in the DLL function to this:

```
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) void sort(const int arr[], int numElements);
```

Since the array is sorted in place, there is no need to return the same array.  In addition, you need to specify the number of elements that the arr will be addressing.

On the C# side, you need to declare the function appropriately.

```
[DllImport("kmp.dll",CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static void sort([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] int[] vhod, int numElements);
```

Hopefully the above is correct for the C# pinvoke.